# multitail for Windows cmd/powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, tail

Is there a program like [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) but for Windows cmd.exe or powershell (not GUI)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It has a GUI but is the only "ready-to-use" tool I know of with multi-log file support: [tail for Win32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/).

Features:

> A few features of Tail:
>
> Watch multiple files in realtime
>
> Detect keyword matches, and highlight occurences
>
> Send mail notifications on keyword matches by SMTP or MAPI
>
> Plugin architecture allows you to write specialised handlers
>
> Can process files of any size on all types of drive (local or networked)

Comment: This seems like a GUI app: http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php

Comment: That's why I began my answer with: "It has a GUI but"

Answer (score 1):

Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell, they talk about the GetFileTail function of PSCX, give it a try..

Answer (score 0):

For log files i need to watch i do:

```
gc MyLogFile.log -Wait -Force | %{ do something with "$_" }
```

Works pretty nicely, it will do only one only do one file a time.